# Interpolate Column data according to uneven timestamp index

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation

I have a data frame in which I need to interpolate empty values of a column according to the index column which is a timestamp which is not evenly spaced.

[image]

In this dataFrame I need to interpolate the x,y,z Coordinate according to the index column which is a timestamp.
The x_coordinate should look like-->  -22, -21.58335, -21.1667, -21

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong by using the pandas interpolate?

See docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: I am trying like this just to fill the x_xoordinate with some value but I am unable to get any output. final_df['x_coordinate'].interpolate(method='linear', axis=0)

Comment: It's a big code and this is just a small part of that with many input files.

Comment: Ok, but I think you need to provide at least a working minimal example.

Comment: I tried with this statement        final_df['x2'] = final_df['x_coordinate'].interpolate() and by this I am getting a new column x2 with values -22.000000 , -21.666667, -21.333333, -21.000000. They are equally spaced as of now, I just need them according to the difference in time.

Comment: I am getting the answer now. I used --> final_df['x2'] = final_df['x_coordinate'].interpolate(method = 'index', axis =0). Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly the method should be index, as the docs say: ‘index’, ‘values’: use the actual numerical values of the index. Please accept my answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use interoplate with method = 'index' like this:

```
dd = {'data': {Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
  Timestamp('2018-10-08 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2018-10-09 00:00:00'): 80.0,
  Timestamp('2018-10-10 00:00:00'): 90.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
df.interpolate(method='index')
```

Output:

```
            data
2018-10-01   0.0
2018-10-08  70.0
2018-10-09  80.0
2018-10-10  90.0
```

Whereas, if you just did interpolate with default, 'linear' method you would get:

```
            data
2018-10-01   0.0
2018-10-08  40.0
2018-10-09  80.0
2018-10-10  90.0
```